# Regex IsMatch aways returns false

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex that is supposed to allow at least 1 number and 1 capital aswell as being between 4 and 15 characters. I hard coded some normal data to test but it always returns false.

```
public static bool PasswordValid(string password)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a - z])(?=.*[A - Z]).{4,15}$");
    return regex.IsMatch("Password1");
}
```

Comment: Try it without the spaces in the character class `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]`

Comment: Remove the spaces from your character classes.   `[A - Z]` is not equivalent to `[A-Z]` in regex.

Comment: This is a common copy/paste issue with Visual Studio guys, I believe OP has no spaces inside the brackets. The point here is that the pattern also requires at least one lowercase letter, and that is not listed as a requirement.